# How to run a Stored Procedure which returns a dataset

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a simple stored procedure(Select Name,ID from MyTable) and I want to call it from C#(or VB.NET) to populate a dataset.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class PaymentDataAccess

    Public Function GetPaymentData() As DataSet

        Dim cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=WORK-HP\BTFSERVER1;Initial Catalog=PaymentReminder;Integrated Security=True"

        Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand("GetPaymentData", cn)

        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Dim sa As New SqlDataAdapter(Cmd)

        cn.Open()

        Dim ds As DataSet = Nothing
        Try

            sa.Fill(ds)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim i As Integer = 7
        End Try
        Return ds

    End Function


End Class
```

I am getting an exception at `sa.Fill(ds)`

```
{"Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: dataSet"}
    System.ArgumentNullException: {"Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: dataSet"}
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
USE [PaymentReminder]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPaymentData] 

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;   
    SELECT * from Payments
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change this line from

```
 Dim ds As DataSet = Nothing
```

to

```
 Dim ds = new DataSet()
```

You need to pass an initialized DataSet to the SqlDataAdapter.Fill method.
Actually your code is like

```
 sa.Fill(Nothing)
```

and of course this is not appreciated by the Fill code.

Comment: I disagree with with my code is like  sa.Fill(Nothing) statement though.

I'm still passing a Dataset to dataadapter and its initial value is nothing.

Comment: @JoeTatavaran: Concerning your 2nd comment, this is the difference between a `ByVal` and `ByRef` parameter. [`SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zxkb3c3d.aspx?cs-lang=vb) accepts a `ByVal` parameter. That is, you're not passing the variable `ds`, whose value could be changed from `Nothing` to a `DataSet` instance by the method; you're passing the value of the variable (`Nothing`), and the method has no way to change your `ds` variable.

Comment: Joe, You should pass a _reference_ to a DataSet, meaning to an area of memory fit to contain a DataSet, but you set the DataSet reference to Nothing and pass this value as _reference_